# tight-spacing and \cdot with siunitx latex package

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I read a lot of post on this subject but none of the answers worked for me. I would like to modify the space before and after the `\cdot` between units. Surprisingly the following code doesn't work. Do you know what's wrong ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\cdot,tight-spacing=true}

\begin{document}
   \si{\watt.\metre^{-2}}
\end{document}
```

I also tried :

- This `\sisetup{inter-unit-product={}\cdot{}}`
- And this `\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\vspace*{-1mm}\cdot\vspace*{-1mm}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tight-spacing` is irrelevant here. If you don't want space around the centered period, use braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{\cdot}},
%  tight-spacing=true,
}

\begin{document}

\si{\watt.\metre^{-2}}

\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\cdot},
}
\si{\watt.\metre^{-2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Arff... I tried the second but not the first (I couldn't find it by myself). I also tried `\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}` but it doesn't works too. Thanks for your answer @egreg.